# ColdFusion XMLSearch issue

Tags: xml, coldfusion

This works:

```
xmlSearch(thisScheduleXml,"/Schedules/Competition[@id = '58']/Match[@status != 'Complete']")>
```

This doesn't:

```
xmlSearch(thisScheduleXml,"/Schedules/Competition[@id = '<cfoutput>#url.competitionID#</cfoutput>']/Match[@status != 'Complete']")>
```

I don't get an obvious error as such; I just get back an empty struct with the second option.

Comment: NEVER MIND...it was related to another issue. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the xpath string as a variable like:

```
<cfset match = "/Schedules/Competition[@id = '#url.competitionID#']/Match[@status != 'Complete']"> 
<cfset xmlSearch(thisScheduleXml,match)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a CFOUTPUT tag in a function argument like that.